# How to interpret disk space requirements on PS3

Tags: ps3

When I buy/download a new game from PSN, a disk space requirement is shown, ie. "7340 MB".

Is it the size of the download? Or is it the size of the final installation?

If it is the latter, how can i calculate the total space needed to download, unpack and install the game?

Comment: I'm not quite sure, but at the point where the difference between downloaded/installed size matters, you're going to want a bigger hard drive anyway; at that point a single DLC, game or even update could push you over the edge of not having enough space.

Answer (score 2):

AFAIK the shown size is the size of the download. You need at least *twice* the space to install game from downloaded package. That's because downloaded package sits on your hard drive while the game is installed: `peak_size` = `package_size` + `install_size`. After the installation package is deleted.

So basically for a 7340Mb game you need *at least* 14680Mb of free space. Usually you need even more space, since extracted data can occupy more space.

Comment: upon install PS3 removes the install candidate, so you wouldnt need to double the size.

Comment: No, I'm interested in the peak_size as @PetrAbdulin describes it. If at any point during `download->install->clean` I would need 7GB + 7GB (download package + installation), then I definitely need twice the free space

Answer (score 0):

7340MB ~= 7GB Hard drive space.

Depending on the game the Total Drive space should be in the requirements listing, or just google the game in question for any installed requirements by the blu-ray disc. However, to me, I would guess that if you're buying this game and downloading it, the install will bump the space up a bit to 8GB and DLC for game is separate from that.

TL;DR: **9GB is a safe amount to want available for this download and install. Depending on Game in question, full game + DLC, if any,
 can amount to >15GB**